# How to match a string against a set of wildcard strings efficiently?

Tags: python

I am looking for a solution to match a single string against a set of wildcard strings. For example

```
>>> match("ab", ["a*", "b*", "*", "c", "*b"])
["a*", "*", "*b"]
```

The order of the output is of no importance.

I will have in the order of 10^4 wildcard strings to match against and I will do around ~10^9 match calls. This means I will probably have to rewrite my code like so:

```
>>> matcher = prepare(["a*", "b*", "*", "c", "*b"]
>>> for line in lines: yield matcher.match("ab")
["a*", "*", "*b"]
```

I've started writing a trie implementation in Python that handles wildcards and I just need to get those corner cases right. Despite this I am curious to hear; **How would you solve this? Are there any Python libraries out there that make me solve this faster?**

Some insights so far:

- Named (Python, re) regular expressions will not help me here since they'll only return one match.
- [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) seems like an awesome library, but is sparsely documented and does not, as I see it, support matching multiple patterns.

Comment: do you mean there are `10**5` strings and `10**4` patterns and you need to return a list of matching patterns for each individual string or is it enough to return a single matching (if any) pattern for each string?

Comment: A few questions.  How long are the strings?  Can the wildcards be literally any unicode character, or is it purely `string.letters`?

Comment: Have you considered using regular expressions?

Comment: J.F Sebastian: I actually want to count the number of occurences of each pattern in a huge log file.

Comment: Kreativitea: Looks like the longest pattern is 980 characters. Not sure about the longest needle string, but maybe 2000...

Answer (score 4):

You could use `FilteredRE2` class from [re2 library](http://code.google.com/p/re2/) with a help from Aho-Corasick algorithm implementation (or similar). From [re2 docs](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp3.html):

> *Required substrings.* Suppose you have an efficient way to check which
>   of a list of strings appear as substrings in a large text (for
>   example, maybe you implemented the Aho-Corasick algorithm), but now
>   your users want to be able to do regular expression searches
>   efficiently too. Regular expressions often have large literal strings
>   in them; if those could be identified, they could be fed into the
>   string searcher, and then the results of the string searcher could be
>   used to filter the set of regular expression searches that are
>   necessary. The FilteredRE2 class implements this analysis. Given a
>   list of regular expressions, it walks the regular expressions to
>   compute a boolean expression involving literal strings and then
>   returns the list of strings. For example, FilteredRE2 converts
>   (hello|hi)world[a-z]+foo into the boolean expression “(helloworld OR
>   hiworld) AND foo” and returns those three strings. Given multiple
>   regular expressions, FilteredRE2 converts each into a boolean
>   expression and returns all the strings involved. Then, after being
>   told which of the strings are present, FilteredRE2 can evaluate each
>   expression to identify the set of regular expressions that could
>   possibly be present. This filtering can reduce the number of actual
>   regular expression searches significantly.
>
> The feasibility of these analyses depends crucially on the simplicity
>   of their input. The first uses the DFA form, while the second uses the
>   parsed regular expression (Regexp*). These kind of analyses would be
>   more complicated (maybe even impossible) if RE2 allowed non-regular
>   features in its regular expressions.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like [Aho-Corasick algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) would work. [esmre](http://code.google.com/p/esmre/) seem to do what I'm looking for. I got this information from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049894/how-to-efficiently-match-an-input-string-against-several-regular-expressions-at).