# speed-boosting string compare

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have a large list of sentences (~5 million) and a reduced list of key-words (~100 words).

I need to know for each key-word, which senteces contain it.
Note, a sentence may any number of key-words (including non at all).

Using conventional pythonic commands takes way too long. I need to boost performance significantly. Any recommendations?

My current code:

```
# df is a dataframe with all of the sentences
context = list()
for w in keywords:
    xdf = df['sentence'].str.contains(w)
    xdf = df[xdf]
    context.append(xdf.values.tolist())
```

It is better than a double loop, but still too slow.

Comment: What is your code, what is the performance? Why do you think it can be improved?

Comment: Can you show how you're constructing your list of ~5 million sentences? Have you thought about sharing the load across multiple processes (**not** threads)? How long does it currently take? What would be the target duration?

Comment: One suggestion would be the Aho-Corasick algorithm as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58566507/how-to-search-a-string-for-a-long-list-of-patterns/58583034#58583034)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach**

Uses the [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) algorithm which allows the processing of several keywords in parallel.

- Uses 200 of the most popular English words as keywords from [deekayen/1-1000.txt](https://gist.github.com/deekayen/4148741)
- Generate Markov random sentences from [Essential Generators module](https://pypi.org/project/essential-generators/)
- Aho-Corasick module from [pyahocorasick](https://pypi.org/project/pyahocorasick/)

**Code**

```
import string
import pandas as pd

import ahocorasick as ahc                          # Word search using Aho-Corasick
from essential_generators import DocumentGenerator # To generate random sentences

# Helper Functions
def make_aho_automaton(keywords):
    '''
        Creates the automation engine
    '''
    A = ahc.Automaton()  # initialize
    for (key, cat) in keywords:
        A.add_word(key, (cat, key)) # add keys and categories
    A.make_automaton() # generate automaton
    return A

def find_keywords(line, A):
    '''
        Finds line  in automation
    '''
    found_keywords = []
    for end_index, (cat, keyw) in A.iter(line):
        start_index = end_index - len(keyw)
        found_keywords.append(keyw)
    return found_keywords

def pre_process_sent(s, make_trans = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)):
    '''
        make lower case
        remove punctuation
        surrond each sentence with whitespace for Aho-Corasick 
    '''
    return f' {s.translate(make_trans).lower()} '
```

**Testing**

```
# 1. Generate Test Dataframe with random sentences
#    Document generator
gen = DocumentGenerator()
#    Place sentences in Dataframe without puntuation and surrounded by spaces
df = pd.DataFrame({'sentence':[pre_process_sent(gen.sentence()) for _ in range(100000)]})

# 2. Use 200 of most common English words as keywords(source: https://gist.github.com/deekayen/4148741)
with open('1-1000.txt', 'r') as f:
    # Most 1K popular English words
    keywords = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
    
    # Use top 100 keywords
    keywords = keywords[:100]
    
    # Generate tuple of keyword, categories for Aho-Corasick 
    # (surround with white space to make boundary sensitive)
    keywords_cat = [(f' {w} ', 1) for w in keywords]


# Generate Automaton
A = make_aho_automaton(keywords_cat)

# Check Dataframe Column for match
df['match'] = df.sentence.apply(lambda x: find_keywords(x, A))
print(df)
```

**Output**

Columns

- sentence : rows of sentences
- match : list of keywords that are in each sentence

df

```
sentence    match
0   rare instances foreign affairs the organisati...    [ the , of , the ]
1   unangam idiom the emperor of these based on t...    [ the , of , these , on , the , from , to ]
2   to dim applied psychology the iaap is conside...    [ to , the , is , to , be , a , that ]
3   the females tests take a biopsy or prescribe ...    [ the , a , or ]
4   evaporate there linear meters   [ there ]
... ... ...
99995   john 1973 discover only []
99996   does it laughter contrary to a series of para...    [ it , to , a , of , or ]
99997   contemporary virginia into chiefdoms    []
99998   repercussions of site of the acm    [ of , of , the ]
99999   history hlabor island followed by a [ by , a ]
100000 rows × 2 columns
```

**Performance**

Summary

- Aho-Corasick ~25X faster on 100,000 sentences using 100 keywords

1. Using Aho-Corasick

   %timeit df.sentence.apply(lambda x: find_keywords(x, A))

Result:    292 ms ± 7.79 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

2. Using Posted Code

   %%timeit

   context = list()
   for w in keywords:
   xdf = df['sentence'].str.contains(w)
   xdf = df[xdf]
   context.append(xdf.values.tolist())

Result: 7.28 s ± 172 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Comment: It worked INSANLEY fast!
I reduced my runtime from hours to a few minutes. Thanks!

Comment: @GuyBarash -- great to hear.

Answer (score -2):

If all you do in python is to slow, maybe (on a linux/mac) use `grep` or `ag` (the silversearcher) instead.